# http-post request for a long String in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am looking to send a very long String, which is an image that is encoded into a String. I need to send that information using POST method. I have implemented the same in `Android using key-value pair`, I need to implement the same in iOS using key-value pair. Please help me with useful resources/approach.

**EDIT 1**

What have I tried

```
[dictionnary setObject:@"admin"  forKey:@"username"];
[dictionnary setObject:@"123123" forKey:@"password"];

NSError *error = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];

NSString *urlString = @"MY CALL URL";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSLog(@"response is obtained");

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

**EDIT 2**

Error I am getting

```
Request Error Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x7ba0120 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://yahoo.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://yahoo.com/}
```

Comment: Question has been updated. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSMutableDictionary

[look this](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add your image string in your post dictionary:

`[dictionnary setObject:imageEncodedString forKey:@"image"];`

Comment: but it is not giving me desired result(No jSON object response )

Comment: data must be converted to base64

Comment: You want to post encoded image to server. With this you are posting your image to server.

Comment: @Daij-Djan every thing is done. Data to be sent is ready, butI get no response